# A primitive sketch program with turtle(an intruduction to 'while' loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The challenge, that is from "From zero to Hero" is the following:

- Create an etch a sketch program
- Have the user enter a pen color, a line length, and an angle
- Use turtle to draw a line based on their specifications
- Let them specify new lines over and over until they enter a line of length 0

Here's what I've done so far:

```
import turtle

penColor = input('Choose a color')
angelone  = input('Choose an algel')
lineLen = input('Chose a line length')

turtle = turtle.Turtle()
while lineLen != '0':    
    turtle.pencolor(penColor)
    turtle.forward(lineLen)
    turtle.right(angelone)
    lineLen = input('Chose a line length')
```

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

What I do wrong here and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.X, `input` returns a string. So `lineLen` and `angelone` aren't numbers even if the user enters nothing but digits.

Try converting those variables to integers before using them to move the turtle.

```
while lineLen != '0':    
    turtle.pencolor(penColor)
    turtle.forward(int(lineLen))
    turtle.right(int(angelone))
```

Comment: Wow! Works! I tried similar logic, but somehow it didn't work out:
I did:
angelone  = int(input('Choose an algel')) and 
lineLen = int(input('Chose a line length')), why that's wrong?

Comment: Did you replace _both_ instances of `lineLen = input('Chose a line length')` with `lineLen = int(input('Chose a line length'))`? If you only replaced one of them, the other will still make your program crash. If you replaced both, then the approach you describe should work fine. (although you would have to change the loop to `while lineLen != 0:`)

Comment: I've got it! I replaced in both places and even changed the while [code] lineLen != 0: [\code], but forget to do it in the last line to [code]     lineLen = input('Chose a line length') [\code].
Thank you very much!